# kohana deployment

Tags: deployment, kohana

I am deploying my site, using kohana, this is the testing site -localhost/koh
and i use htaccess to remove the index.
I am able to successfully put it in something like www.site.com/koh but i am struggling to 
place it on the root folder, and making it work with htaccess, or how do i make it work, by placing index in root and keeping all other files in koh folder?
anyone can help?
thanks

Comment: What do you mean by struggling? What are you doing and what isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to your question:

[Kohana Deployment outside the root and more](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/installation/deployment)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running v3... these steps should get you in the right direction:

Place index.php in the folder you want Kohana to run from (in your case, the root public html folder).

In index.php, make sure the paths for $application, $modules and $system are correct. (They can be absolute or relative (from the location of index.php.)) For example, to keep your application folder just above the webroot you would use "../application", and so on for modules and system.

In bootstrap.php, check that base_url is set appropriately for your environment (set it to "/").

Lastly, make sure the RewriteBase in .htaccess is set to "/" as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your case this is what your index file should look like and be placed under the root folder:

```
/**
 * The directory in which your application specific resources are located.
 * The application directory must contain the bootstrap.php file.
 *
 * @see  http://kohanaframework.org/guide/about.install#application
 */
$application = './koh';

/**
 * The directory in which your modules are located.
 *
 * @see  http://kohanaframework.org/guide/about.install#modules
 */
$modules = './koh/modules';

/**
 * The directory in which the Kohana resources are located. The system
 * directory must contain the classes/kohana.php file.
 *
 * @see  http://kohanaframework.org/guide/about.install#system
 */
$system = './koh/system';
```

Check out my htaccess below for an example of what yours should look like.  Mine is a modified version of example.htaccess.  Forces 301 redirect to uri's without trailing slashes.

Here is how I structured my deployment for Kohana.  It allows you to have multiple applications using a single set of core files.

```
www/
  apps/
    web/
      cache/
      classes/
      config/
      logs/
      media/
      messages/
      pub/
        index.php
        .htaccess
        robots.txt
  lib/
    modules/
    system/
```

here's my modified .htaccess

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b - [F,L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Here's the relevant lines in the index.php

```
/**
 * The directory in which your application specific resources are located.
 * The application directory must contain the bootstrap.php file.
 *
 * @see  http://kohanaframework.org/guide/about.install#application
 */
$application = '../';

/**
 * The directory in which your modules are located.
 *
 * @see  http://kohanaframework.org/guide/about.install#modules
 */
$modules = '../../../lib/modules';

/**
 * The directory in which the Kohana resources are located. The system
 * directory must contain the classes/kohana.php file.
 *
 * @see  http://kohanaframework.org/guide/about.install#system
 */
$system = '../../../lib/system';
```

NB: This setup requires you to configure your web server to access each app.